# Should I say "copula" or "copula function"? Is the latter superfluous?

Tags: terminology, definition, copula

I am writing a paper involving copulas and have been thinking of whether I should say "copula function" or just "copula", as I am not sure whether the term "copula" contains "function" in itself or not. So I checked Wikipedia, Mathematics Stack Exchange and Cross Validated and found somewhat different definitions and descriptions.

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)), we have

> In probability theory and statistics, a copula is a multivariate cumulative distribution **function** for which the marginal probability distribution of each variable is uniform on the interval [0, 1].

In Mathematics Stack Exchange, the [copula tag description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/copula/info) reads

> A copula is a multivariate cumulative distribution **function** for which the marginal probability distribution of each variable is uniform on the unit interval.

Meanwhile, in Cross Validated, the [copula tag description](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/copula/info) reads

> A copula is a multivariate **distribution** with uniform marginal distributions.

I guess the word "copula" does contain "function" in itself, so "copula" is sufficient while "copula function" is superfluous. On the other hand, there are 86000 Google hits for "copula function", so perhaps one can write either way...
I also guess our tag description is imprecise and we should edit it.
Please let me know if I am mistaken.

Comment: (1) "Copula function" is ambiguous: would it refer to the CDF or the PDF, for instance? (2) The underlying concept is that of the joint *distribution* on $[0,1]^n,$ but for purposes of elementary mathematical analysis a copula usually is defined as a function with particular properties (see Nelsen's book). Mathematically, the wiki on [math.se] has it right while conceptually, our wiki has it right. That's the result of two different perspectives; it's neither erroneous nor imprecise.